# double type Multiplication in C# giving me wrong values

Tags: c#

I am getting the wrong values at the time of multiplication following is my code

```
double tranAmt = Convert.ToDouble(5079.98);
double res = tranAmt * 100 ;
```

showing me result as 507997.9999999994

Expected result is 507998.0

what i am missing.

Comment: Then use `decimal`

Comment: If you want more precise number, use `decimal` instead. `double` data type has precision rounding issue.

Comment: [See here for full documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)